# Open the form after closing it causes crash

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, forms

```
Loading loadingForm = new Loading();
        private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Thread loading = new Thread(new ThreadStart(startLoading));
            loading.Start();
            new Thread(() => sendEmail()
            ).Start();
        }
        public void closeLoading()
        {
            if (loadingForm.InvokeRequired)
                loadingForm.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate ()
                {
                    closeLoading();
                });
            else
                loadingForm.Close();
        }
        public void startLoading()
        {
            if (loadingForm != null)
                Application.Run(loadingForm);
            else
            {
                loadingForm = new Loading();
                Application.Run(loadingForm);
            }
        }
```

Basicly this code is supposed to open a Loading form in a thread and do some other process in another thread.

But my applications crashes if i close once the Loading form after it's done loading and press the button "Send" a second time. It says to make sure the form still exist and if it wasn't released. So in StartLoading i've just check if my form isn't "null". It never goes to else part. If I do loadingForm = new Loading(); in start loading  without anything else, it will open the form and stays there and never close. The closeLoading is called from the process in the second thread.

How can i fix the problem?  i keep getting the error to make sure if my form wasn't released

EDIT:

I don't know if i'm clear enough.

The Close part work. So if i open the loading form ONCE it opens and then closes when it's finished. The crash part happens after i open the loading form a second time. It says the message above.

Comment: You don't want to have multiple UI threads.  You should really have a single UI thread to handle your entire UI.

Comment: There is no conceivable point in you trying to re-use the `loadingForm` variable.   This code is also excessively dangerous, you get to debug [this problem](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsui_team/archive/2012/10/31/debugging-windows-forms-application-hangs-during-systemevents.userpreferencechanged.aspx).  That was meant to scare you out of doing this.  The worker thread must *only* call sendEmail(), nothing else.  Use BackgroundWorker, its RunWorkerCompleted event is convenient to close the window.

Comment: As long as you maintain a reference in your code to the loadingForm, it will not be released by the garbage collector. You should either hide the form or set the form to null after disposing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a thread I used a task, and opened the loading screen as a dialog to prevent interaction with the primary form.

```
Loading loadingForm = new Loading();
btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    new Task(() => sendEmail()
    ).Start();
    startLoading();
}
public void closeLoading()
{
    if (loadingForm.InvokeRequired)
    {
        loadingForm.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
        {
            closeLoading();
        });
    }
    else
    {
        loadingForm.Hide();
    }
}
private void startLoading()
{
    if (loadingForm == null)
    {
        loadingForm = new Loading();
    }
    loadingForm.ShowDialog();
}


private void sendEmail()
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    closeLoading();
}
```

Comment: Thanks this will do :)